# Second url loading of WebView always leads to white screen

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to call a fileviewer (like: `https://website.com/fileviewer.asp?file=myfile.pdf`) and need to be logged in first. So I first call the login service of the website, then in `onPageFinished` I try to call the fileviewer url.

I've tried almost anything I could find on the Internet in this function :

- `.reload()`
- `.invalidate()`
- `.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
- `.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);`
- `.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`
- removed the call to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`

But nothing works correctly, I'm always getting a white screen after the first call (successful).

So, what should I do...? 
Thanks for your help.